# RSolve produces a solution which is not complete?

Tags: difference-equations

Consider the following solution of a recurrence relation in two variables

```
RSolve[f[x + 1, y] == f[x, y + 1], f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> {{f[x, y] -> C[1][x + y]}}

It suggests that the recurrence relation is in general satisfied by any function that depends on the sum of `x` and `y` only. However, it is trivial to see that we also have

```
f[x + 1, y] == f[x, y + 1] /. f[x_, y_] -> (-1)^(x - y) C[2][x + y] // Simplify
```

> True

which uses a function different from the type of solution returned by `RSolve`, but still properly solves the recurrence relation.

Does this mean that `RSolve` does not return the most general solution? Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how `RSolve` should work?